# Gmail is ignoring "display:none"

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

I have a query that Gmail is ignoring `display:none`.

What to do? In email HTML for hiding a row or div.

Comment: If you want certain things to be hidden in an email, the easiest way is to not include them at all.

Comment: What query?  Please explain more.

Comment: @leppie I think he means a support request

Answer (score 72, accepted):

If `style="display:none"` does not work in Gmail, put `style="display:none !important;"` 
and it works in Gmail.

Comment: Just my opinion: Pekka's answer makes more sense. If you are hiding the element, just get rid of it all together.

Comment: @Jasper You may be hidding for using in a different media query. Even if Gmail doesn't support it, other mail apps do so, like iOS native app.

Comment: This is not a good answer.  Gmail does not respect display:none.  The only way this works is if you put declare display:none!important inline on the element.  But if you do that, you won't be able to overwrite it.

Comment: Works great if you want to embed some parseable info that shouldn't be displayed to the user.

Comment: This might work with gmail (and you can overwrite it with classes) but it does not work in outlook anymore as it dislikes !important

Answer (score 44):

For those reaching here with a similar problem relating to mobile/desktop email development in and Gmail - if you're using media queries and showing/hiding content, the embedded css will be unable to overwrite the inline !important declaration. Instead you can use overflow:hidden, like so :

`<div class="mobile" style="width:0; overflow:hidden;float:left; display:none"></div>`

In your embedded media queries you will naturally undo these styles to reveal the div, and then hide the desktop version of the content.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .mobile {
  display : block !important;
  width : auto !important;
  overflow : visible !important;
  float : none !important;
 }
 .desktop {
  display : none !important;
 }
}
```

Unfortunately the height property doesn't work in Gmail, otherwise it would be a better solution, given that this creates a section of whitespace below the visible content equal to the height of the div.

Comment: note the above should be read display and not disply. I tried to edit the comment but stackoverflow won't allow edits of less than 6 chars.

Comment: @luke THANK YOU!

To anyone that is reading this in the future like i just did. If you want to get rid of that ugly white space. just do a line-height: 1px; then in your media query add in the proper line-height. I found that it worked best on the TR instead of the div or td.

Comment: Just to make note, we discovered using this method for having a mobile version of an email was not ideal, since forwarding the email in Outlook to another person would display both the mobile and desktop content. Now we try and build emails only by using display:block on table elements (tr, td) to adapt them for mobile screens.

Comment: For the record, this workaround no longer appears to be functional. Gmail is trying VERY hard to prevent people from conditionally detecting their platform.

Comment: It still works on Gmail, but you need to use `max-height: 0` and use it on a block level element (a div - it is not working on a table or a table row).

Comment: Yes! After trying several variations, setting `max-height: 0` worked for me!

Answer (score 29):

Though this has already been answered I just thought I'd chip in with a solution that really worked for me in case anyone has this problem in the future. It's really a combination of the above answers and something else that I found online.

The issue that I was having was for Gmail and Outlook. As per the OP, the mobile content I had would not hide in Gmail (Explorer, Firefox and Chrome) or Outlook (2007,2010 & 2013). I solved this by using the following code.

Here's my mobile content:

```
<!--[if !mso 9]><!-->
<tr>
  <td style="padding-bottom:20px;" id="mobile">
    <div id="gmail" style="display:none;width:0;overflow:hidden;float:left;max-height:0;">
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td>
    <img src="imageurl" style="border:0;display:block;width:100%;max-height:391px;" />
          </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
          <td style="border-left-style:solid;border-left-width:1px;border-left-color:#d5e1eb;border-right-style:solid;border-right-width:1px;border-right-color:#d5e1eb;background:#f7fafd;padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:22px;color:#1c1651;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;text-align:left;" id="mobiletext" align="left">We're now on Twitter</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="border-left-style:solid;border-left-width:1px;border-left-color:#d5e1eb;border-right-style:solid;border-right-width:1px;border-right-color:#d5e1eb;background:#f7fafd;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:13px;color:#585858;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;text-align:left;line-height:24px;" id="mobiletext"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color:#0068ca;">Follow us now</a> for some more info.
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="imageurl" style="border:0;display:block;width:100%;max-height:37px;" />
          </td>
    </tr>                               
  </table>  
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

And here's the CSS:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:300px) and (max-width: 500px) { /* MOBILE CODE */
*[id=mobile] {
    width:300px!important;
    height:auto!important;
    display:block!important;
    overflow:visible!important;
    line-height:100%!important;
  }
*[id=gmail] {  
    display:block!important;
    width:auto!important;
    overflow:visible!important;
    float:none !important;
    height:inherit!important;
    max-height:inherit!important;
  }
```

**Fixes for Outlook**

So as you can see from the HTML code above, wrapping all the content in these tags;

`<!--[if !mso 9]><!-->   <!--<![endif]-->`,

hides the content for the Outlook versions that I mentioned. For all the other email clients, the `display:none;` works just fine. I also saw that you can also use `mso-hide:all` to hide things for Outlook but I thought this was a little easier than placing that code inline.

**Fixes for Gmail**

Now for Gmail, you can see that I created a 'special' `id` called `gmail` which I then applied to a div within the `<td>`. I tried COUNTLESS other methods of using things such as `overflow:hidden` inline and all manner of other combinations but this is what worked for me.

So in short, wrapping the content in the `<td>` in a `<div>` which then contains the `overflow:hidden,width:0` etc then overwriting these styles by giving the div an `id` of, in my case `gmail` solved the problem for me.

Anyway, maybe someone will find this helpful in future!

Comment: Extraordinarily great answer to the question. Thanks for posting this a year later - it saved our bacon. The Gmail/Outlook email css idiocy has been a real drag but this solved it nicely.

Comment: You are most welcome, I'm glad this has helped, figuring it out was like finding a goldmine!

Comment: YOU ARE A GENIUS!!!! This needs to be the top voted best answer for real. I've tried about 7 different approaches, all of them requiring massive class additions to my css, and all in all, not working across all email clients. This was so simple and WORKED!!!!!

Comment: tested this, it can hide, but it cannot show. i think the reason is because media queries is not supported in gmail. so anything inside @media only screen and (min-width:300px) and (max-width: 500px) is ignored by gmail.

Comment: This is some genius work! You really did an outstanding Job. This is the most generic and best possible solution I came across mainly because you took care of responsive styles as well as structured it well to handle the worst possible case! Thumbs Up Man!!!

Comment: Thanks for that answer, really helped a lot, it seems to work reliable.

Comment: @ErwinKaddy perhaps you are discussing Gmail App vs Gmail web

Answer (score 24):

Using `display:none !important;` resolves the issue with gmail but it is then ignored by Outlook 2007 and 2010.  Got round this using `display:none; display:none !important;`
That way gmail uses one version and Outlook 2007 and 2010 use the other.

Comment: You can use `mso-hide: all;` for Outlook 2007-13

Comment: Gmail completely ignores display: none

Answer (score 7):

It has been said already `display:none !important;` works, but no one has stated a use case for this so I'll give one I was working on when I found this question and solution on SO.

I was creating a multi-part email with plain/text and html. In the source, html is generated from template files, and the plain text is created from stripping tags from the full e-mail.

To include additional text in the plain-text that isn't shown in the html, the easiest way is to wrap it in a `<div style="display:none !important>` that will be stripped out when the plain-text is generated. For instance if this is your template:

```
<p>This is part of an html message template.</p>
<div style="display:none !important">=================================</div>
<div style="border-top:3px solid black;margin-top:1em;">
   <p>This is some footer text below a black line</p>
</div>
```

The HTML will render as expected (no bunch of ='s) and the plain-text with all the div's stripped will be:

```
This is part of an html message template.
=========================================
This is some footer text below a black line.
```

Comment: Or even simpler: to hide the backup text if the receiver has no html support in their client and sees an unreadable bunch of html.

Answer (score 6):

Remove the element from your source code completely.

E-Mail clients are very strict about some CSS rules. Also, seeing as no JavaScript can be executed inside the E-Mail, a `display: none` has no function there anyway, does it?

Comment: Found the answer Its working for gmail style="display:none !important;"

Comment: Many mobile devices support media query's, so if you are designing a responsive this has several use cases.

Comment: What does JavaScript have to do with `display: none`?

Comment: @Jamey what point is there in hiding an element when you're not going to display it under some circumstances? Support for Media Queries in clients is dismal. https://litmus.com/help/email-clients/media-query-support/ how else to do this than with JS?

Comment: @Twistar and GMail allows for media queries in E-Mails?

Comment: @Pekka You might want to hide something completely under certain circumstances. But you're right, gmail doesn't support media queries, so it's a kind of useless for gmail specifically.

Comment: @Jamey but I can't see a reason to have an element in an E-Mail that I don't want to show. (Or at least no *legitimate* reason. Maybe it's possible to smuggle a tracking pixel in that way, no idea. But that would be really evil!)

Comment: I'm using it to create a div with preview text.

Comment: This may have been a good answer several years ago, but nowadays, the issue is more nuanced.  We design our emails "mobile first", and then use media queries to provide a large-screen-friendly version where possible.  `display: none` comes in handy with hiding certain elements in the large-screen version.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for this, very helpful for me.

Try max-height for Gmail this should pick it up. then use max-height:inherit !important; in the CSS this should remove the spacing issue:

```
<div class="mobile" style="display:none; width:0px; max-height:0px; overflow:hidden;">

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.mobile {
display:block !important;
margin: 0;
padding:0;
overflow : visible !important;
width:auto !important;
max-height:inherit !important;
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Stack Overflow way of saying thank you.

Comment: Thank you! This solution worked for me best. The ones above left me with white space where the hidden element was.

Answer (score 2):

In order to hide an element in an HTML email and have it work in Gmail you need to zero it out and adjust the sizing in your CSS (which Gmail will ignore).

Like so:

```
<style>
    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) { 
    *[class~=show_on_mobile] {
        display : block !important;
        width : auto !important;
        max-height: inherit !important;
        overflow : visible !important;
        float : none !important;
    }
</style>

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<!--[if !mso]><!-->
    <td style="width: 0; max-height: 0; overflow: hidden; float: left;">
    </td>
</tr>
<!--<![endif]-->
</table>
```

Additionally, the added conditional comment covers you for Outlook 07.

Comment: Your markup looks odd, what does the markup look like for MSO? Surely you're not duplicating it.

Comment: My standard template is here if you'd like to review it:  https://github.com/dcondrey/html-email/blob/master/template/campaign.html  It will render predictably across more clients than any other template you'll find.

Comment: Do you have tables or rows within your email template that you show/hide for desktop/mobile? I have a bunch of tables with classes like `hide-for-desktop` and `hide-for-small` which is part of the Zurb Ink documentation. I don't see any examples of handling this sort of setup for Outlook and GMail in your standard template. Generally I am finding my template works in _either_ GMail or Outlook, but not both.

Answer (score 1):

I have a situation in which I just had a couple of words. I used font-size:0px;.

`<div style="font-size:0px">foo bar</div>`

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Dan S., another example that I use frequently.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  p[class="hidden"] { /* I use this format to get past Yahoo Mail */
    display: block !important;
    visibility: visible !important;
    max-height: none !important;
  }
}

<td>
  <p class="hidden" style="display:none;visibility:hidden;max-height:0px;">You can't see me.</p>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

With great pleasure, I would like to share this news with everyone that gmail now supports 'display:none' CSS property on testing by [EmailMonks](http://www.emailmonks.com). But you need to apply a class with CSS while using 'display:none', inorder to be untouched by the inlining tool.

You can read more [here](http://www.emailmonks.com/blog/email-coding/gmail-supports-display-none-css/)

Answer (score -3):

If you are experiencing issues with Gmail the fix stated in Number three worked for me as well. I applied a similar approach using div tags and overrides in line and then defining a CSS style in the head tag specific for gmail.  Anytime that I want to hide something from outlook desktop I do the following: if !mso. See example below:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
    <html>
    <head>

    <style type="text/css">
    So my code looks like this: 
    @media screen and (max-width : 480px) { div[id=gmail] {display:block!important;
        width:100%!important;
        overflow:visible!important;
        float:none !important;
        height:inherit!important;
        max-height:inherit!important;}
    }
    </style>
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

<!--And the in the i have the following setting inline-->
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<div id="gmail" style=
"display:none;width:0;overflow:hidden;float:left;max-height:0;">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#E9E9E8"
align="center"><![if !mso]>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<table width="133" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style=
"border: 1px solid #c6c6c5;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<!--My content--></table>
</td>
</tr>
<![endif]></table>
</div>
</td>
<!--This worked for me in Android 4.2 /4.1 /apple iOS
desktop web based: gmail, yahoo, Aol, Outlook.com in IE / FF and Chrome
desktop: outlook 2010--></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```