# Why Gmail doesn't apply HTML-ized Dataframe Styler?

Tags: python, html, pandas

I got a really challenging problem. I'm trying to write a Python script to send styled Dataframe to Gmails. I need to have it showing like below in Email body, which I succeed in HTML file.

[image]

However, what I received in Email like this:

[image]

It seems Gmail doesn't apply the CSS style for font colors.

My code is below:

```
# Load sample data
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv');df
# Fill missing values
df.fillna('-',inplace = True);df
# Add 2 level column name
columns=[
    ('Overview', 'Date'),
    ('Overview', 'City'),

    ('Group A','col_a'),
    ('Group A','col_b'),

    ('Group B','col_a'),
    ('Group B','col_b'),
    ('Group B','col_c'),
];

df.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(columns);df

# Define function for font color
def color_highlight(val):
    try:
        pct = float(val.split('(',1)[1].split('%',1)[0])
        if pct<-1:
            color = 'red'
        elif pct>1:
            color = 'green'
        else: color='black'
        return 'color: %s' % color
    except IndexError:
        return 'color: black'

# Use Pandas styler to apply UDF and export HTML string
s2 = df.style.applymap(color_highlight,
                      subset=pd.IndexSlice[:
                                           ,[    ('Group A','col_a'),
                                                ('Group A','col_b'),

                                                ('Group B','col_a'),
                                                ('Group B','col_b'),
                                                ('Group B','col_c')
                                            ]]) \
    .set_table_attributes('border="1" class="dataframe" style="border-collapse: collapse;"') \
    .render().split('\n')
s2 = ''.join(s2)
s2
html = s2

# Send email
import smtplib
import time
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication

sender = 'alichenxiang@gmail.com'
recipients = ['myboss@gmail.com','myteam@gmail.com']

msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = 'REMINDER: Data alert'
msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = ", ".join(recipients)

#put the html into the email body
html = MIMEText(html, 'html')
msg.attach(html)

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.connect('smtp.gmail.com',587)

server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.ehlo()

username = 'alichenxiang@gmail.com'
password = 'mypassword'
server.login(username,password)

#server.sendmail(sender, tolist, msg.as_string())
server.sendmail(sender, recipients, msg.as_string())
server.quit()
print("Success")
```

Here is the generated HTML:

```
<style  type="text/css" >    #T_dcf16f78_5384_11e8_972a_8c859034ed75row0_col2 {            color:  black;        }    #T_dcf16f78_5384_11e8_972a_8c859034ed75row0_col3 {            color:  green;        }    #T_dcf16f78_5384_11e8_972a_8c859034ed75row0_col4 {            color:  black;        }    #T_dcf16f78_5384_11e8_972a_8c859034ed75row0_col5 {            color:  red;        }    #T_dcf16f78_5384_11e8_972a_8c859034ed75row0_col6 {            color:  green;        }    #T_dcf16f78_5384_11e8_972a_8c859034ed75row1_col2 {            color:  black;        }    #T_dcf16f78_5384_11e8_972a_8c859034ed75row1_col3 {            color:  red;        }    #T_dcf16f78_5384_11e8_972a_8c859034ed75row1_col4 {            color:  black;        }    #T_dcf16f78_5384_11e8_972a_8c859034ed75row1_col5 {            color:  red;        }    #T_dcf16f78_5384_11e8_972a_8c859034ed75row1_col6 {            color:  black;        }    #T_dcf16f78_5384_11e8_972a_8c859034ed75row2_col2 {            color:  black;        }    #T_dcf16f78_5384_11e8_972a_8c859034ed75row2_col3 {            color:  red;        }    #T_dcf16f78_5384_11e8_972a_8c859034ed75row2_col4 {            color:  black;        }    #T_dcf16f78_5384_11e8_972a_8c859034ed75row2_col5 {            color:  green;        }    #T_dcf16f78_5384_11e8_972a_8c859034ed75row2_col6 {            color:  black;        }</style>  <table id="T_dcf16f78_5384_11e8_972a_8c859034ed75" border="1" class="dataframe" style="border-collapse: collapse;"> <thead>    <tr>         <th class="blank level0" ></th>         <th class="col_heading level0 col0" colspan=2>Overview</th>         <th class="col_heading level0 col2" colspan=2>Group A</th>         <th class="col_heading level0 col4" colspan=3>Group B</th>     </tr>    <tr>         <th class="blank level1" ></th>         <th class="col_heading level1 col0" >Date</th>         <th class="col_heading level1 col1" >City</th>         <th class="col_heading level1 col2" >col_a</th>         <th class="col_heading level1 col3" >col_b</th>         <th class="col_heading level1 col4" >col_a</th>         <th class="col_heading level1 col5" >col_b</th>         <th class="col_heading level1 col6" >col_c</th>     </tr></thead> <tbody>    <tr>         <th id="T_dcf16f78_5384_11e8_972a_8c859034ed75level0_row0" class="row_heading level0 row0" >0</th>         <td id="T_dcf16f78_5384_11e8_972a_8c859034ed75row0_col0" class="data row0 col0" >20180507</td>         <td id="T_dcf16f78_5384_11e8_972a_8c859034ed75row0_col1" class="data row0 col1" >Madrid</td>         <td id="T_dcf16f78_5384_11e8_972a_8c859034ed75row0_col2" class="data row0 col2" >1,657(0.3%)</td>         <td id="T_dcf16f78_5384_11e8_972a_8c859034ed75row0_col3" class="data row0 col3" >839(1.2%)</td>         <td id="T_dcf16f78_5384_11e8_972a_8c859034ed75row0_col4" class="data row0 col4" >75,746(0.2%)</td>         <td id="T_dcf16f78_5384_11e8_972a_8c859034ed75row0_col5" class="data row0 col5" >4,168(-8.1%)</td>         <td id="T_dcf16f78_5384_11e8_972a_8c859034ed75row0_col6" class="data row0 col6" >3,486(2.1%)</td>     </tr>    <tr>         <th id="T_dcf16f78_5384_11e8_972a_8c859034ed75level0_row1" class="row_heading level0 row1" >1</th>         <td id="T_dcf16f78_5384_11e8_972a_8c859034ed75row1_col0" class="data row1 col0" >20180507</td>         <td id="T_dcf16f78_5384_11e8_972a_8c859034ed75row1_col1" class="data row1 col1" >Tokyo</td>         <td id="T_dcf16f78_5384_11e8_972a_8c859034ed75row1_col2" class="data row1 col2" >33(0.0%)</td>         <td id="T_dcf16f78_5384_11e8_972a_8c859034ed75row1_col3" class="data row1 col3" >18(-5.3%)</td>         <td id="T_dcf16f78_5384_11e8_972a_8c859034ed75row1_col4" class="data row1 col4" >13,344(0.1%)</td>         <td id="T_dcf16f78_5384_11e8_972a_8c859034ed75row1_col5" class="data row1 col5" >981(-2.3%)</td>         <td id="T_dcf16f78_5384_11e8_972a_8c859034ed75row1_col6" class="data row1 col6" >1,416(0.1%)</td>     </tr>    <tr>         <th id="T_dcf16f78_5384_11e8_972a_8c859034ed75level0_row2" class="row_heading level0 row2" >2</th>         <td id="T_dcf16f78_5384_11e8_972a_8c859034ed75row2_col0" class="data row2 col0" >20180507</td>         <td id="T_dcf16f78_5384_11e8_972a_8c859034ed75row2_col1" class="data row2 col1" >London</td>         <td id="T_dcf16f78_5384_11e8_972a_8c859034ed75row2_col2" class="data row2 col2" >-</td>         <td id="T_dcf16f78_5384_11e8_972a_8c859034ed75row2_col3" class="data row2 col3" >37(-2.6%)</td>         <td id="T_dcf16f78_5384_11e8_972a_8c859034ed75row2_col4" class="data row2 col4" >10,434(0.0%)</td>         <td id="T_dcf16f78_5384_11e8_972a_8c859034ed75row2_col5" class="data row2 col5" >53(1.9%)</td>         <td id="T_dcf16f78_5384_11e8_972a_8c859034ed75row2_col6" class="data row2 col6" >1(0.0%)</td>     </tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: Does it look right when you send it to any other mail service? Or open the email from any other mail client?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gmail CSS Styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19572437/gmail-css-styling)

Comment: You should post the generated HTML rather than just a screenshot of the rendered results.

Comment: Just added the generated HTML @GrishaLevit.

Comment: Unfortunately, we're using Google suite. So I may have to make it in Gmail. @Anthony

Comment: Thanks @MaxvonHippel~ However, I don't how to generate Gmail friendly CSS from pandas dataframe in Python.

Answer (score 4):

As Gmail don't support css styles in head, one need to process it and attach the styles to individual elements as inline styles.

You can have you own function to process your html before attaching to mail or you can use python **premailer** package for same.

```
    from premailer import transform


    post_transform_html = transform(html, pretty_print=True)
    msg.attach(post_transform_html)
```

It will work as expected.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use inline CSS in html email template because email template does not capture css in head.

Comment: Thanks @RaviBhushan~ However, I don't how to generate HTML from pandas dataframe in Python.

Comment: take a look at this http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html