# Outlook.com force fixed width 150px

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

Since a few weeks i am facing an issue with the formatting of all the emails I send to all Microsoft accounts, i.e., Hotmail.com, Outlook.com, etc.

What I see is that Outlook adds an extra style to my html, and in particular a class that automatically sets the width of all the html elements at 150px, making it basically impossible to read and click.

**For exemple:**

```
.rps_c2c1 * { width: 150px!important; height: auto!important; }
```

*_rps* is the external class added to the div that contains my html.
This happens as I have media queries in my code. But that's weird, because the same html was displayed correctly two months ago.

I really don't know how to face this issue. Outlook support does not help me at all.

This is the result in Outlook.com

```
<div class="rps_75ff">
<style type="text/css">
<!-- .rps_75ff #x_outlook a
{ padding: 0; }
.rps_75ff .x_ReadMsgBody
{ width: 100%; }
.rps_75ff .x_ExternalClass
{ width: 100%; line-height: 100%; background: #d7d7d7; min-width: 600px!important; }
.rps_75ff .x_forceWidth
{ width: 600px!important; }
.rps_75ff .x_forceWidth .x_tableDX
{ width: 280px!important; }
.rps_75ff .x_ExternalClass .x_forceWidth
{ width: 600px!important; }
.rps_75ff bodyx_[w8f] .x_forceWidth
{ width: 600px!important; }
.rps_75ff .x_ExternalClass, .rps_75ff .x_ExternalClass p, .rps_75ff .x_ExternalClass span, .rps_75ff .x_ExternalClass font, .rps_75ff .x_ExternalClass td, .rps_75ff .x_ExternalClass div
{ line-height: 100%; }
.rps_75ff bodyx_[class=w8f] .x_mainTable
{ width: 600px!important; min-width: 600px!important; max-width: 600px!important; }
.rps_75ff bodyx_[class=w8f] .x_tableDX
{ float: right; }
.rps_75ff bodyx_[class=w8f] .x_tableSX
{ float: left; }
.rps_75ff bodyx_[class=w8f] .x_phoneText
{ text-align: right!important; }
.rps_75ff bodyx_[class=w8f]
{ background-color: #e8e8e8; color: #000000; font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; width: 100%!important; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.rps_75ff bodyx_[class=w8f] img
{ border: 0; max-width: 100%; }
.rps_75ff bodyx_[class=w8f] a img
{ border: none; }
.rps_75ff bodyx_[class=w8f] table td
{ border-collapse: collapse; }
.rps_75ff bodyx_[class=w8f] .x_datiContainer
{ display: block!important; float: none!important; height: 100%!important; width: 100%!important; overflow: normal!important; }
.rps_75ff bodyx_[class=w8f] .x_rightImage
{ width: 150px!important; height: 150px!important; border: 5px solid red!important; }
.rps_75ff bodyx_[class=w8f] .x_tablePrezziDx .x_btn
{ float: right; }
.rps_75ff *
{ width: 600px!important; }
.rps_75ff *
{ display: block!important; float: none!important; height: 100%!important; width: 100%!important; overflow: normal!important; }
.rps_75ff *
{ width: 150px!important; height: auto!important; }
.rps_75ff iframe.x_attachment, .rps_75ff iframe.x_attachment-pdf
{ border: 10px solid transparent!important; width: 40%!important; float: left!important; }
.rps_75ff imgx_[class=banner]
{ width: 100%!important; height: auto!important; max-width: 100%; }
.rps_75ff .x_overflowing, .rps_75ff .x_overflowing *
{ border-color: gold!important; color: gold!important; font-size: 8px!important; outline: none!important; display: none!important; }
.rps_75ff .x_inner_image .x_snow
{ content: ''; background: none; font-family: Androgyne; height: 100%; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; z-index: 0; }
--></style>
<div>
<div class="...">EMAIL CONTENT</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using inline styles?

Comment: I also have inline style into the html

Comment: Odd, your inline style should always win in that case, unless it's being stripped out.

Comment: @zik I updated with the code

Comment: @zik inline style doesnt always win, the most specific generally wins

Comment: @Deckerz but .rps_75ff * overwrites almost everything... :(

Comment: What are you using to test the emails? Are you using something like Litmus? This may help; https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: @zik I use all the browser/client-safe conditions. This happens when I have <style> into the head of html. But the bug started at least a couple of months ago. The same code did not cause any problem before.
Also, outlook should ignore style into head, didn't it?

Comment: I answered a question a long time ago about HTML emails as I used to code them (long time ago now) but I'm not sure it's still relevant but it might help. Take a look here ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013670/gmail-is-ignoring-displaynone/16479964#16479964

I thought all email clients ignored styles in the `<head>`