# email templates, outlook and right align

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, email-templates

I am having an issue with outlook with my email template.
In all other email applications my template looks like, but outlook always left aligns my buttons. This is what I have:

```
<a style="display: block; text-align: right; margin-bottom: 10px;" href="-PRODUCT2URL-" target="_blank"><img style="display: inline-block" align-right src="https://marketing-image-production.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/8b32ba0f98a4a49b628c0ccd072134aa3d287d9eb72a728573ec4f219a6139800392ddcc8413db10724b2c9070bee75141cc2ef7926f4af80372811faa299682.jpg" /></a>
```

Not only does outlook ignore the right align, but it also doesn't have the margin bottom.
Does anyone know how I can get outlook to allow me to right align this button?

Comment: I answered a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013670/gmail-is-ignoring-displaynone/16479964#16479964, which may help. There are some specific styles that you can use to target Outlook.

Comment: margins are not supported in Email client

Comment: add in the code for the outer table in which the anchor sits so we can give a definite answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply `text-align: right;` to the table cell where the href is located.

`margin` is problematic in Outlook. In the desktop 2011-16, it ignores `margin`, but will respond to `Margin`. So `Margin-bottom` will work, but `margin-bottom` is ignored.

For more information of the fun you will encounter with Outlook, check out these resources:

- https://litmus.com/help/email-clients/outlookcom-margins/
- https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

it is very much related to how you are structuring your email template:
while making a simple html page "**div**" is a basic building block that we user to structure the page,

but while building an html email template we need to user table as a basic building block, means we should use "table" and its child tags "**tr**", "**th**" for making an email templates. this will resolve most of out positioning issues.